# scale setting for all NPCs and player characters

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

I'm having some difficulty finding when players have their "scale" set. I can see that creatures have theirs set from the template, going to assume NPCs are the same too - but I haven't been able to spot when this gets set for player characters and feel like I've looked pretty hard..

Anybody able to point me in the right direction? I was kind of hoping to make it so that all npcs/players/creatures will scale randomly from between -0.1 and +0.15 of the given scale modifier.

Any possible help no how to accomplish this would be great,
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look like player/pet scale is set by the client :
http://www.ac-web.org/forums/showthread.php?118128-How-do-you-change-the-default-pet-size

Here is an example for set scale by race on Trinity :
https://community.trinitycore.org/topic/14830-how-to-go-about-changing-player-characters-normal-size/

So this code in Player.cpp  should randomly set scale from 0.0 (-1.1) to 1.15 (+0.15).

```
void Player::SetupRaceSize()
{
    uint8 race = getRace();
    float size;
    {
        float r3 = 0.9 + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(1.15-0.9)));
        SetObjectScale(1.0f);
    }
}

Comment existing SetObjectScale  :
//SetObjectScale(1.0f);
SetupRaceSize();
```